# Expand array every time a newline (↵) character exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, newline

I'm trying to expand an array every time a newline character occurs, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I am getting the contents of a textarea and creating an array based on where each `tab` occurs.

I create with a 4-element array called `lines` as follows: `["A widget:↵", "X component;↵", "Y component; and↵", "Z component.↵↵"]`

I ultimately want a 9-element array like this: `["A widget:", "↵", "X component;", "↵", "Y component; and", "↵", "Z component.," "↵", "↵"]`

My current code is this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
      var newlinehere = lines[i].indexOf("\n");
          if (newlinehere > 0){
                lines.splice(newlinehere, 0, "NEWLINEHERE");
          }
}
```

I cannot find the `↵` to know where to splice the array.  "\n" isn't working.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

EDIT:  I edited my comment to correct my original code.  I entered it wrong initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Array.map()`, and `Array.concat()` methods to split and flatten a final array.

```js
var items = [ "item1\n", "item2\n\n", "item3" ]

var items2 = items.map(function(item){
  
  return item.split("\n");
})

var flatten = [].concat.apply([], items2)

console.log(flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.flatMap(s => s.split(/(↵)/)).filter(x => x.length)
# => ["A widget:", "↵", "X component;", "↵", "Y component; and", "↵",
#     "Z component.", "↵", "↵"]
```

`split` splits on a delimiter; but if there is a capture group inside the regular expression, it will also yield the delimiters in the split array. With `flatMap`, we split all the strings and concatenate all the results into one array. However, if the delimiter was at the start or at the end of a string, we'll get an empty segment there, so at the end `filter` gets rid of those.

This is assuming you have 'DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS' (U+21B5), and not 'LINE FEED (LF)' (U+000A), or 'CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)' (U+000D). If you have one of the latter, replace `↵` with `\n`, or `\r`, as appropriate. (It would also be much clearer if you wrote `["A widget:\n", "X component;\n", "Y component; and\n", "Z component.\n\n"]`)

EDIT: `flatMap` is not yet available on all platforms; you can use this instead:

```
[].concat(...arr.map(s => s.split(/(↵)/))).filter(x => x.length)
```